# Removing a comma from a c++ output

Tags: c++, vector, iostream

I wrote this program that sorts numbers in vectors from greatest to least, it works great but the only thing that is bugging me is trying to remove the comma from the last number. Heres my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<int> vi1, vi2, vi3;
    srand(987);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) vi1.push_back(rand() % 10);
    sort(vi1.begin(), vi1.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) vi2.push_back(rand() % 10);
    sort(vi2.begin(), vi2.end())

    while(!vi1.empty() && !vi2.empty()) {
        if(vi1.back()>=vi2.back()) {
            vi3.push_back(vi1.back());
            vi1.pop_back();
        }
        else {
            vi3.push_back(vi2.back());
            vi2.pop_back();
        }
    }

    while(!vi1.empty()) {
        vi3.push_back(vi1.back());
        vi1.pop_back();
    }
    while(!vi2.empty()) {
        vi3.push_back(vi2.back());
        vi2.pop_back();
    }

    for (auto i = vi3.begin(); i != vi3.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ", ";
    cout << "\nBye..." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output

```
9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
Bye...
```

as you can see after the last 0 there is a comma which doesn't make sense grammatically speaking. How can I remove that comma?

Comment: The comma is either after every element but the last one, or before every element but the first one. Pick one of these conditions and use it to print or not print the comma.

Comment: Try this, using a vairable as flag to indentify when add a comma: `int bCount = 0;`  ...  `cout <<  (bCount++ > 0 ? ", " : "")  << *i`.

Comment: Or, like someone answered:  `cout << (i == vi3.begin()? "" : ", ") << *i`

Comment: `boost::algorithm::join` will do this for you, if you don't mind bringing it in

Comment: _@rajkod_ I formatted your code for better readability, but there's a lot of completely irrelevant code you should consider to remove. Make it a [mcve]  focussing on the problem you want to resolve.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than *removing* the simplest way is just to print commas only for other values than the first:

```
for (auto i = vi3.begin(); i != vi3.end(); ++i) {
    if(i != vi3.begin()) {
        cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << *i;
}
```

I am using this idiom regularly to format e.g. SQL parameter lists, or similar where a delimiter isn't wanted after the last element but for any others.
There are other ways to detect the *first element* (e.g. using a `bool` variable initialized to `true` before the loop starts, and set to `false` upon the first iteration).
For your example it seems just checking for `vi3.begin()` is the easiest and most natural way.

Here's the generic variant in pseudo code:

```
bool isFirstOutput = true;
for_each(element in list) {
    if(not isFirstOutput) {
        print delimiter;
    }
    print element;
    isFirstOutput = false;
}
```

Comment: If performance is a concern, the if can be omitted, and all elements except the last one can be printed using that loop. Then the last one can be printed outside the loop without the comma.

Comment: @SenselessCoder I seriously doubt this would improve performance in a significant manner.

Comment: It could have *some* impact with very large element sizes.

Comment: @SenselessCoder You probably meant an impact regarding _large sizes_ of the collection, not the elements themselves. Even then we can use _branch prediction hints_ for the compiler to optimize.

Comment: You're right, I made a typo there. Compiler would very likely optimize this, I forgot about it. I'll test this to see if it does.

Comment: @SenselessCoder As mentioned it's a really common idiom I am using in various programming languages all the time. I've never been stuck in a performance problem doing so so far.

Comment: If the cost of printing doesn't make the cost of the if not first check insignificant, whoever wrote the print routines deserves a raise and free drinks at the pub.

Comment: @user4581301 _"free drinks at the pub"_ What's your favorite place? :-D

Comment: http://oceanparkpizza.com/ Not much of a drinker, mind you. I'm there for the lasagna.

Answer (score 0):

If `begin`, `end` are at least bidirectional iterators (as yours are),
you can just check initially that `begin` != `end`;  if not print nothing; if so print
`", "`-puncuated elements incrementing `begin != std::prev(end)`, and
finally print `*begin()`. like so:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <utility>

template<typename OStream, typename BiIter, typename Punct>
void punctuated(OStream && out, Punct && punct, BiIter begin, BiIter end)
{
    if (begin != end) {
        for (--end  ;begin != end; ++begin) {
            std::forward<OStream>(out) << *begin << std::forward<Punct>(punct);
        }
        std::forward<OStream>(out) << *begin;
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v0;
    std::vector<int> v1{{1}};
    std::list<int> l{{1,2}};
    std::set<int>s{{3,4,5,6,7}};
    std::cout << "v0 [";
    punctuated(std::cout,",",v0.begin(),v0.end());
    std::cout << "]\n";
    std::cout << "v1 [";
    punctuated(std::cout,",",v1.begin(),v1.end());
    std::cout << "]\n";
    std::cout << "l [";
    punctuated(std::cout,",",l.begin(),l.end());
    std::cout << "]\n";
    std::cout << "s [";
    punctuated(std::cout,"|",s.begin(),s.end());
    std::cout << "]\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp && ./a.out
v0 []
v1 [1]
l [1,2]
s [3|4|5|6|7]
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8396777c2f17b0b)